# How can I use inline CSS in a b:row?

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I know that the `style` attribute can be used in a `b:panel`, for example. How can I use it in a `b:row`?

I want to do something like this:

```
<b:row style="margin-top: 60px;">
    ...
</b:row>
```

But the attribute is omitted in the final HTML page and I do not want to use the `styleClass` attribute.

### Update

This has been solved in the most current version (0.6.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved in the most current version (0.6.6), which came out a few days ago.